# php, get between html markup, regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have a html block like this

```
<option value="berkshire">Berkshire                                                
<option value="reading">Reading</option></optgroup>
<option value="buckinghamshire">Buckinghamshire
<option value="milton-keynes">Milton Keynes</option></optgroup>
<option value="east-sussex">East Sussex<option value="brighton">Brighton</option>    </optgroup>
```

And I need to extract the value and name (e.g value= berkshire , name = Berkshire

So far I've tried two methods :
1.

```
function get_between($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}


  $value = get_between($htmlContent, 'value="', '">');
  $name = get_between($htmlContent, "$value\">", '');
```

The problem with this is that it gets only the the first name-value (berkshire and Berkshire) . If I make $r[1] dymanic and set $r[2], $r[4] etc with while or foreach I get only the value and the name is not returned anymore for some reasons that I don't understand .

2.Regex 
  I've tried to extract at least the "value"  but couldn't get the proper regex so for the "name" I didn't even have a start  point.

```
   $pattern = "//";
preg_match_all($pattern,$htmlContent, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML block is consistent you could of course use a simple regex for *extraction*:

```
preg_match_all('#<option\s+value="([^"]+)">([^<]*)#i')
// requires to strip trailing whitespace from the name in $matches[2]
```

But if you want to actually fetch content from real-world HTML then it's easier to use a DOM parser like phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) for simplicity:

```
foreach (qp($html)->find("option") as $opt) {
    echo $name = $opt->text(),  $opt->attr("value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It only gets the first name-value because you didn't attempt to split between the options. Here is my solution for your problem (not regex). These lines go after the `get_between()` function:

```
$opt = explode('<option ', $html);
foreach ($opt as $split_html) {
    $value = get_between($split_html, 'value="', '">');
    $name = get_between($split_html, "$value\">", ' ');
    echo $value ." ". $name . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using DomDocument to normalize the HTML input and Xpath to get the values you're interested in:

```
$results = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//option[@value]') as $node) {
    $results[] = array(
        'value' => $node->getAttribute('value'), 
        'name' => trim($node->nodeValue)
    );
}
var_dump($results);
```

If you remove the `@` in front of the third line, you will see the errors inside the HTML chunk.